# wordpress send value from post to page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new in php and wordpress.

I want to parse xml and show result on post.

This is xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<all_emp>
<emp_detail>
<emp emp_name="john"><img>john_1.jpg</img></emp>
<emp emp_name="john"><img>john_2.jpg</img></emp>
<emp emp_name="john"><img>john_3.jpg</img></emp>
<emp emp_name="marry"><img>marry_1.jpg</img></emp>
<emp emp_name="marry"><img>marry_2.jpg</img></emp>
<emp emp_name="david"><img>david_1.jpg</img></emp>
</emp_detail>
</all_emp>
```

I use shortcode in functions.php to show it in post.

```
$url = 'https://.../emp_test.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file("$url") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$names = array();   
$emps = $xml->children()->emp_detail->emp ; 
foreach($emps as $emp_detail)
{
    $source = (string)$emp_detail->attributes()->emp_name; 
    $names[]= $source; 
} 
$names = array_unique($names); 
return implode("<br />", $names);
```

So, in post, i has result like:

```
john
marry
david
```

After that, how to click john, it will send string is john to page?

Comment: Can you please add your code so we can get idea ?

Comment: Can you please describe it more clearly? Where should this result show ? front end or back end ? from where you are inserting this data `john : male : 26` ? 
What i can think if the jhon is a user and you are getting data from usermeta then just use a ajax call to do that display part.

Comment: @Jalpa: I was update my question.

Comment: @M.KHossain: I was update my question. It like i want to show emp name in post and when click one emp, it will send emp name to page and use it to get emp img.

Comment: @1234abcd what is your url of page that you have to redirect ?

Comment: @Jalpa: Just custom page.

Answer (score 0):

Let me be the first one to say this is not the most ideal way to do this. However you can create template for the page(s) that will handle these names. Then create a wordpress Page that uses this template. Lets say the page you create is: `http://[SITEURL]/name-handling-page`

Then you can modify your shortcode above to return urls instead of jsutthe names:

```
$names = array_unique($names); 
$links = array();
foreach ($names as $name)
{
        $links[] = get_permalink('name-handling-page')."?name=$name"; //replace name-handling-page with slug or id of newly created page
}
return implode("<br />", $links);
```

Comment: Your mean i need display all emp name in page and display img in another page? page --> page, not post --> page?